Identify incoming SSHD processes by forwarded socket file
I have a Docker container running SSHD which receives SSH connections from multiple remote machines. I need to identify and terminate the connection coming from one particular machine.
The connections:

Each incoming connection is from a different machine.
Each incoming connection forwards a Unix socket file on the container to a TCP port on the remote machine. Each remote machine forwards a different container.
Forwarding that one port is the only thing these connections do; they do not start an interactive session or run any commands.
Every incoming connection logs in as the same user.
Each remote machine has a different auth key which it uses to log in.
The code which executes the SSH connection on the remote machines is under my control, so if there is some option I can pass to ssh or set in ssh_config which will make it easier to ID the connections, I have the option to do that.

What I know:

I know the serial number of the machine whose connection I need to kill.
I know which socket file that connection will be forwarding.
I know which SSH auth key the connection will have logged in with.
I do not know what IP address or hostname the connection will be coming from.

What I've tried so far:

ps -aux will show me the SSHD processes for all the incoming connections. However, I cannot tell which incoming connection comes from which remote machine.
If I could identify which process corresponded to which SSH auth key, that would suffice, but there's no obvious way to even begin with that.
The most promising option would seem to be identifying which process has the corresponding socket file open, but I haven't been able to do that yet:

cat /proc/net/unix tells me which socket files are open, but not what processes each one is opened by
lsof is supposed to list which processes have which files open. However, when I tested it by running it when I had a single incoming connection:

The output did not list the socket file I knew to be open anywhere
The output for the SSHD processes in question (there were two of them, one running as root and the other as the log-in user) showed their only open files to be /proc/${PID}/cwd, /proc/${PID}/root, /proc/${PID}/exe, and 6-8 numbered files in /proc/${PID}/fd/






Found the solution: lsof can tell you which processes have a given socket file open. However, Docker, by default, restricts containers such that processes inside the container cannot read /proc/${PID}/fd/${FD_NUM}, even if the process trying to do the reading is running as root, which is why lsof couldn't tell what processes had what files opened.
Running the SSHD container with --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE tells Docker not to block such operations, allowing lsof to work correctly.
More specifically: lsof -t "${SOCKET_FILE}" will return a list of PIDs which have the given socket file open.
